# asp.net detailsview how to set edit field width

Tags: asp.net, width, detailsview

I have a detailsview bound to a LINQ SQL query.

Display is fine, but when user switch to Edit mode, the width of all fields to edit is REDUCED, and there is no wordwrap!

How can I set width according to database column length for instance, or to a fixed value of mine?

Answer (score 0):

You can use EditRowStyle and/or EditDataRowStyle properties of DV. You can set styles for individual control in the EditItemTemplate.
You can share some screenshot or code if there is any problem setting those properties.